# Why does the socket accept method return the address?

Tags: sockets

In my projects I never came across a situation where I found the need to use sockets in more than in the straight forward way: create server and accept/create client and connect. Nothing fancy.

From the documentation of the accept method I read that the address returned by accept is the address of the peer. So far so good. But two aspects irritate me:

1. I never seem to need the address later on.
2. Can't I just call get_peer_name if I need the address?

Am I missing something? Does get_peer_name return something different?

Comment: You can just pass `NULL` for the address pointer to `accept()` if you don't care about the peer address.

Comment: @pmacfarlane ah, thanks! This fact that there is a mechanism to ignore it also means that it’s actually a normal use case to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're missing anything; `getpeername()` can be used to obtain the same information later on.

Whether you need the information depends on your use case; e.g. some servers might want to know their client's IP address so they can send UDP packets back to it.

As for why `accept()` returns this info when there is another mechanism to get it, I suspect that is due to historical reasons; e.g. originally `accept()` was the only way to get the info, until someone realized it would be convenient to also have a way to obtain the info later on (e.g. for TCP connections where the code using the socket didn't have access to the `accept()` call because `accept()` was called from within a different library), so they added `getpeername()`, but kept `accept()` the same as it was to avoid breaking backwards compatibility.